Problem with push notifications in production React Native
When I test the notification system in a test environment using expo go, everything works as it should. However, when I create an APK through expo and install it on the phone, everything works except when I click on the notification, there is a problem because it does not redirect to the finished screen.
Screen1.js:
const getStoredNotifications = async () => {
    const notifications = await AsyncStorage.getItem('notifications');
    return notifications ? JSON.parse(notifications) : [];
};

const storeNotification = async (notificationId) => {
    const notifications = await getStoredNotifications();
    const updatedNotifications = [...notifications, notificationId];
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('notifications', JSON.stringify(updatedNotifications));
};

const scheduleReminder = async (item, immediate = false) => {
    const notifications = await getStoredNotifications();
  
    if (!immediate && notifications.includes(item.id)) {
      console.log(`Reminder already scheduled for item: ${decode(item.name)}`);
      return;
    }

    const itemStartDateTime = new Date(`${item.date}T${item.startTime}`);
    const triggerDate = immediate ? new Date(Date.now() + 5 * 1000) : new Date(itemStartDateTime.getTime() - 60 * 60 * 1000);
  
    if (triggerDate > new Date()) {    
      const latitude = parseFloat(item.latitude);
      const longitude = parseFloat(item.longitude);
      
      console.log(`Parsed coordinates: Latitude = ${latitude}, Longitude = ${longitude}`);
      
      if (!isNaN(latitude) && !isNaN(longitude)) {
        const formattedItem = {
          id: item.id,
          name: item.name,
          description: item.description,
          date: item.date,
          time: `${item.startTime} - ${item.endTime}`,
          location: item.location,
          latitude: latitude,
          longitude: longitude,
          phone: item.phone,
          image: item.imagePath,
          price: item.ticketPrice,
        };

        console.log('Scheduling reminder with item:', JSON.stringify(formattedItem));
  
        const notificationId = await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
          content: {
            title: `Starting soon!`,
            body: `Your item ${formattedItem.name} starts ${immediate ? 'soon' : 'in 1 hour'}.`,
            data: { item: formattedItem, channelId: 'reminders' },
          },
          trigger: { date: triggerDate },
          channelId: 'reminders',
        });
  
        console.log(`Reminder scheduled for item: ${formattedItem.name} with ID: ${notificationId}`);
        if (!immediate) {
          await storeNotification(item.id);
        }
      } else {
        console.warn('Invalid coordinates received in reminder:', `Latitude: ${latitude}`, `Longitude: ${longitude}`);
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`Trigger date is in the past. No reminder scheduled for item: ${item.name}`);
    }
  };

const fetchStoredItems = useCallback(async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const user = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('user'));
      if (!user) {
        Alert.alert("Not Logged In", "Please log in.");
        return;
      }
      const response = await fetch(`${config.BASE_URL}api/fetchStoredItems?userId=${user.id}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data.success) {
        const validItems = data.items.filter(item => {
          const itemEndDate = moment(item.date).add(7, 'days');
          const isArchived = item.status === 'Archived';
          const isPastEndDate = moment().isAfter(itemEndDate);
  
          return !isArchived && !isPastEndDate;
        });
  
        setStoredItems(validItems);
  
        const notifications = await getStoredNotifications();
  
        const unprocessedItems = validItems.filter(item => !notifications.includes(item.id));
  
        for (const item of unprocessedItems) {
          await scheduleReminder(item);
        }
      } else {
        Alert.alert("Error", "Unable to retrieve stored items.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to fetch stored items', error);
      Alert.alert("Error", "Network issue.");
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

const handleTestReminder = async () => {
    if (storedItems.length === 0) {
      Alert.alert("No Stored Items", "You currently have no stored items to test.");
      return;
    }
    const item = storedItems[0];
    await scheduleReminder(item, true);
};

<TouchableOpacity onPress={handleTestReminder} style={styles.testButton}>
          <Text style={styles.testButtonText}>Test Reminder</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

App.js:
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import Navigation from './Components/StackNavigation';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import { navigationRef } from './Components/NavigationService';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { decode } from 'utf8';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [isNavigating, setIsNavigating] = useState(false);
  const notificationListener = useRef(null);

  const checkNotificationPermissions = async () => {
    const { status } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = status;

    if (status !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }

    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      Alert.alert('Permissions', 'Notification permission is not enabled.');
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  };

  const saveReminderData = async (item) => {
    try {
      const itemData = JSON.stringify(item);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(`reminder_${item.id}`, itemData);
      console.log('Reminder data saved locally.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to save reminder data:', error);
    }
  };

  const removeReminderData = async (itemId) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem(`reminder_${itemId}`);
      console.log('Reminder data removed.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to remove reminder data:', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadResourcesAndDataAsync() {
      try {
        const hasPermission = await checkNotificationPermissions();
        if (!hasPermission) {
          console.log('Notifications are not allowed');
        }

        Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
          handleNotification: async () => ({
            shouldShowAlert: true,
            shouldPlaySound: true,
            shouldSetBadge: false,
          }),
        });

        const existingChannel = await Notifications.getNotificationChannelAsync('reminders');
        if (!existingChannel) {
          await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('reminders', {
            name: 'Reminders',
            importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.HIGH,
            vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
            lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
          });
          console.log('Notification channel created: reminders');
        } else {
          console.log('Notification channel already exists:', existingChannel);
        }

        await Font.loadAsync({
          // Fonts
        });

        const handleNotificationResponse = async (response) => {
          console.log('Notification response received:', response);
      
          const { identifier, content } = response.notification?.request || {};
          const channelId = content?.data?.channelId || 'reminders';
          console.log(`Notification ID: ${identifier}`);
          console.log(`Notification Channel: ${channelId}`);
      
          const item = content?.data?.item;

          console.log('Received item data:', item);

          if (item) {
            const formattedItem = {
              id: item.id,
              name: item.name,
              description: item.description || 'No description',
              date: item.date,
              time: item.time,
              location: item.location || 'N/A',
              latitude: parseFloat(item.latitude),
              longitude: parseFloat(item.longitude),
              phone: item.phone || 'No phone',
              image: item.image,
              price: item.price || 'N/A',
              openedFromNotification: true,
          };

              await removeReminderData(item.id);
      
              if (!isNaN(formattedItem.latitude) && !isNaN(formattedItem.longitude)) {
                  setIsNavigating(true);
                  navigationRef.current?.navigate('Item Details', { item: formattedItem });
                  setTimeout(() => setIsNavigating(false), 1000);
              } else {
                  console.warn('Invalid coordinates received in notification');
              }
          } else {
              console.error('Notification data is missing or invalid', item);
          }
      };

        const subscription = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(handleNotificationResponse);

        return () => {
          subscription.remove();
        };
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        setFontsLoaded(true);
        SplashScreen.hideAsync();
      }
    }

    loadResourcesAndDataAsync();
  }, []);

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return <Navigation />;
}

When I run in production, and look at the logs, this shows me:
2024-08-11 23:31:35.473 19652-19690 EGL_emulation           com.example.MyApplication  D  app_time_stats: avg=34.05ms min=10.96ms max=140.43ms count=28
2024-08-11 23:31:37.991 19652-19690 EGL_emulation           com.example.MyApplication  D  app_time_stats: avg=176.36ms min=14.18ms max=2028.39ms count=14
2024-08-11 23:31:39.013 19652-19690 EGL_emulation           com.example.MyApplication  D  app_time_stats: avg=30.25ms min=2.52ms max=98.53ms count=30
2024-08-11 23:31:39.202 19652-19707 ReactNativeJS           com.example.MyApplication  I  Parsed coordinates: Latitude = 44.77935, Longitude = 20.439291
2024-08-11 23:31:39.523 19652-19707 ReactNativeJS           com.example.MyApplication  I  Notification scheduled for event: Children's Summer Games with ID: bd4741d9-416f-4e3b-87b6-7aac3fa6e574
2024-08-11 23:31:41.458 19652-19690 EGL_emulation           com.example.MyApplication  D  app_time_stats: avg=123.84ms min=2.02ms max=1899.74ms count=19
2024-08-11 23:31:42.483 19652-19690 EGL_emulation           com.example.MyApplication  D  app_time_stats: avg=20.06ms min=2.49ms max=33.73ms count=39
2024-08-11 23:31:44.474 19652-19807 expo-notifications      com.example.MyApplication  D  Notification request "bd4741d9-416f-4e3b-87b6-7aac3fa6e574" will not trigger in the future, removing.
2024-08-11 23:31:44.946 19652-19690 EGL_emulation           com.example.MyApplication  D  app_time_stats: avg=130.94ms min=2.37ms max=2005.04ms count=18
2024-08-11 23:31:45.967 19652-19690 EGL_emulation           com.example.MyApplication  D  app_time_stats: avg=26.19ms min=4.42ms max=58.36ms count=33
2024-08-11 23:31:48.521 19652-19652 ReactNativeJS           com.example.MyApplication  D  [native] ExpoNotificationLifecycleListener contains an unmarshaled notification response. Skipping.
2024-08-11 23:31:48.731 19652-19707 ReactNativeJS           com.example.MyApplication  I  'Notification response received:', { notification: 
                                                                                                       { request: 
                                                                                                          { trigger: 
                                                                                                             { channelId: null,
                                                                                                               value: 1723411904202,
                                                                                                               repeats: false,
                                                                                                               type: 'date' },
                                                                                                            content: 
                                                                                                             { autoDismiss: true,
                                                                                                               title: 'Starting Soon!',
                                                                                                               badge: null,
                                                                                                               sticky: false,
                                                                                                               sound: 'default',
                                                                                                               body: 'Your event Children's Summer Games is starting soon.',
                                                                                                               subtitle: null },
                                                                                                            identifier: 'bd4741d9-416f-4e3b-87b6-7aac3fa6e574' },
                                                                                                         date: 1723411904459 },
                                                                                                      actionIdentifier: 'expo.modules.notifications.actions.DEFAULT' }
2024-08-11 23:31:48.731 19652-19707 ReactNativeJS           com.example.MyApplication  I  Notification ID: bd4741d9-416f-4e3b-87b6-7aac3fa6e574
2024-08-11 23:31:48.731 19652-19707 ReactNativeJS           com.example.MyApplication  I  Notification Channel: reminders
2024-08-11 23:31:48.732 19652-19707 ReactNativeJS           com.example.MyApplication  E  'Notification data is missing or invalid', undefined
2024-08-11 23:31:48.883 19652-19708 unknown:ReactNative     com.example.MyApplication  E  console.error: Notification data is missing or invalid undefined, js engine: hermes, stack:
                                                                                                    _construct@1:141787
                                                                                                    Wrapper@1:141441
                                                                                                    _callSuper@1:139426
                                                                                                    SyntheticError@1:140918
                                                                                                    reactConsoleErrorHandler@1:140579
                                                                                                    ?anon_0_@1:733473
                                                                                                    asyncGeneratorStep@1:120466
                                                                                                    _next@1:120723
                                                                                                    anonymous@1:120675
                                                                                                    anonymous@1:120596
                                                                                                    handleNotificationResponse@1:733873
                                                                                                    anonymous@1:1623892
2024-08-11 23:31:49.140 19652-19690 EGL_emulation           com.example.MyApplication  D  app_time_stats: avg=206.85ms min=15.57ms max=2618.55ms count=15
2024-08-11 23:31:50.145 19652-19690 EGL_emulation           com.example.MyApplication  D  app_time_stats: avg=31.36ms min=2.32ms max=67.14ms count=25
2024-08-11 23:31:50.703 19652-19657 MyApplication           com.example.MyApplication  W  Cleared Reference was only reachable from finalizer (only reported once)
2024-08-11 23:31:50.747 19652-19657 MyApplication           com.example.MyApplication  I  Background concurrent mark compact GC freed 8462KB AllocSpace bytes, 22(1008KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 11MB/23MB, paused 1.575ms,2.825ms total 180.853ms
2024-08-11 23:31:52.680 19652-19690 EGL_emulation           com.example.MyApplication  D  app_time_stats: avg=137.83ms min=13.51ms max=2026.10ms count=18
2024-08-11 23:31:53.683 19652-19690 EGL_emulation           com.example.MyApplication  D  app_time_stats: avg=20.53ms min=2.39ms max=39.92ms count=37

